# Odoo error: "Document type: Mass Mailing, Operation: read" when delete filter "My Mailings"

Tags: email, odoo-12

[Error: Email Marketing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNfuE.png)

My Odoo version is 12, the error appears in the "Email Marketing" module, when I remove the "My Mailings" filter, I have reviewed all the registration rules created for this object in: "Settings / Technical / Security / Acces Rule "and there is no validation for my system where it is excluded that a user does not have permissions to see the campaign of another user, I have tried preparing an environment from scratch and this problem does not appear.

I need to know apart from the registration rules what else I can review.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access rights for this object, who can read , create, delete and write.